# How to combine two UUIDv4 strings to a single unique UUIDv4 string

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I have two UUIDv4 strings which I want to combine to a single unique UUIDv4 string, such that the input UUID strings always generate the same UUIDv4 string regardless of their insertion index.

```
def generate_uuidv4(uuid1,uuid2):
    """
    Combine to single unique uuidv4 string which is replicable based on input strings regardless of insert position
    """
    return uuidv4_string
```

Note: Input ids are position agnostic.

Comment: What is the insertion point? What have you tried?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I want to have a unique hash of the two uuids in a uuidv4 format. I have tried combining first half of the first uuid string and second half of second uuid string

Comment: Something like an XOR between both UUIDs…? It's questionable how that influences the uniqueness aspect; adding two unique values together doesn't necessarily make it more unique. Can you describe the use case a bit more…?

Comment: I have a time consuming function which takes in two inputs and calculates a result.
My input objects have a UUID field which identify them. I want to cache the result in a db such that the result has a identifier of uuidv4 which can be a combination of the input UUIDs @deceze

Comment: Can't you simply concatenate the two IDs into one longer id for the purpose of caching…?

Comment: My web-api has to follow a certain OpenApi3 spec which specifies the identifier to be UUIDv4

Comment: Does it have to be an UUIDv4 specifically? Because version 4 is supposed to be fully random, and trying to generate it based on other information may be problematic, for example by making collisions more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward approach would probably be to combine the int representation of two UUIDs with bitwise operators and construct a new UUID from it:

```
>>> from uuid import *

>>> u1 = uuid4()
>>> u2 = uuid4()
>>> u3 = UUID(int=u1.int ^ u2.int, version=4)
>>> u1, u2, u3
(UUID('2266aff1-a7be-4c71-bc0d-987779f68bd3'),
 UUID('284c5065-299f-479c-9d6b-d353012795d7'), 
 UUID('0a2aff94-8e21-4bed-a166-4b2478d11e04'))
```

I can't tell you what the best operator for combining here would be, an XOR, OR, AND, or whatever else. Reasoning about how that affects the random distribution of the result is beyond my pay grade.

Comment: You should probably add version=4 to set the correct version bits of the resultant UUID.

Comment: This looks like a good answer. Also I am quite sure we wont end up with the same uuid simply because the 128bit space large enough to make that probability very close to zero.